# I cannot gain access to my new MySQL user account

Tags: mysql

I re-installed MySQL 8.0 because I wanted to create a new user. Originally, my user was the default root account with a blank password. I created a new user with a different username and password but when I access PhpMyAdmin from the localhost, it only lets me log in with the credentials of my old root account. Upon using the credentials for the new account I created, it gives me this error:

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'corp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm frustrated to say the least. Why is this happening and how can I successfully use my new user account?

Comment: Can you post the queries used to create the new user?

Comment: Can you show the info that phpMyAdmin displays for the user account? My first thought is that you created the user with account access from `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. MySQL treats theses as different, so the account needs to have permission to be accessed using `localhost` if that's how it will be used. However, this is a guess, hence why it's a comment; without seeing how the account is set up, I really can't give a definite answer.

Comment: @Spudley Interestingly enough it says I don't have privileges on the root account, and I can't see the user accounts as well, but that would make sense. I created the user in the installer when i was reinstalling MySQL instead of creating it in the console, which probably answers franklinsijo's question as well. Is there some other way I can see?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a try this:

1. Login with root on MySQL console.
2. Do this query:

   ALTER USER 'corp'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH MYSQL_NATIVE_PASSWORD BY 'mypassword';

This might make possible for a plain text password authentication.